# Multiple Spells Regressions

Tags: regression, panel-data

I am working with a panel data set in which I can observe not only if you were unemployed in the past year but also how many times you were unemployed and the duration of each unemployment spell. I would like the run a regression to identify how variables (such as job-search methods used each unemployment spell) affect the length of the unemployment spell.

The difficulties are threefold. First, each individual can report having multiple spells within a year, and the number of spells within a year differ person to person. Second, it is likely that there is some sort of heterogeneity that makes it impossible to treat each unemployment spell as a single observation and use individual fixed effects to denote the same individual. Finally, in the panel data, not every person is interviewed every year.

Basically, I was wondering if there is a standard method for dealing with this kind of multiple spell regression. I have done some searching, but all the papers I have found are fairly old, so I do not know if they are still relevant. Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea, but I haven't tried it on your data: Consider

- employment as an "event",
- length of unemployment as a "time to event",
- persons who are not interviewed in a year as

  - "censored" if you never see them again, or
  - "missing" if they come back.

This may allow you to use [Survival Analysis with Recurrent Events](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4339761/). The epidemiologists have methods for dealing with "events" that happen to people multiple times, and they are well used to missing and / or censored observations. I think that their literature may be useful to you. I think something similar to [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4477955/) may help you deal with the missingness in the data (as long as you don't have reason to suspect the unobserved years for a person are deterministic).